# How to call a set focus on a form creation

Tags: pascal, lazarus

I'm creating a small application with some 'Search' hotkeys, F1 to F4 to search into different tables of a database, so I've created a TPageControl to hold the search fields and also display the results, so I have 1 PageControl and 4 tab sheets, but I'm trying to put one if statement to set the focus on the proper search field and I'm calling it on the OnShow event of the TPageControl, but I'm getting a error message: Form:TForm cannot focus

If I didnt got it all wrong, it's because the text field cannot be found, considering I'm showing the page before the application can create the elements inside of this page, so, how can I edit this code or where can I use it to make it works, just remembering that I need to call this procedures with the hotkeys later on.

The procedure I'm using to set the focus is just a simple IF with 4 conditions in my real case:

```
procedure TForm.searchFocus; begin 
if pgcSearches.TabIndex=0 then begin
editFieldNames.SetFocus;
end
else if pgcSearches.TabIndex=1 then begin
editFieldAdresses.SetFocus
end;
end;
```

Comment: Did you try setting ActiveControl?

Comment: Can't find this over the web (not something I can understand at least), can you give a example please?

Comment: ActiveControl := editFieldNames;

Comment: It's a possibility, but I can't figure out how can I use it, especialy with your 'short' example, but thanks for the awser I suppose

Comment: There's not much to extend upon... Replace "editFieldNames.SetFocus" with "ActiveControl := editFieldNames", it either works or not.

Comment: I'ts not the explanation itself, it's just a more visual aid, like a code for example, like they teach me on another place, I'm new to programming and it's been a hard time to figure out some stuff, but you're completely right, fits like a glove. Thanks very much once more.

Comment: Code is not visual aid. Don't get into the habit of requesting ready code, you'll lose time you could spend on learning programming.

Comment: I'm a beginner and I don't have access to a course, so this kinda of code help me a lot (even with a 'hello world'), but I'll work harder on it, and thanks very much for your support ^^

Answer (score 1):

A more 'explicit' help from another forum:

```
procedure TfrmMain.pcSearchesChange;
begin
case pcSearches.TabIndex of
0: ActiveControl:=edtSearchSongs;
1: ActiveControl:=edtSearchBibles;
2: ActiveControl:=edtSearchWarning;
end;

if Visible then
ActiveControl.SetFocus;
end;
```

Comment: Why do you call ActiveControl.SetFocus here? This is done automatically.

Comment: I'm learning programming by myself, and sadly I don't have any kind of place to get a course in my town (almost living in Small Vile =/), and it's the first time I heard about ActiveControl on my learning, so I'm kinda lost yet, I'll try without it later, thanks for the suggestion ^^

Comment: Don't worry. A course probably wouldn't have told you about ActiveControl either.